# Certificate Chain doesn't inculeded in singed pdf

Tags: java, pdf, certificate, itext, digital-signature

i have similar problem. i try to sign pdf with mobile signature. i use itextpdf-5.1.3.jar,bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar while signig.

```
X509Certificate root0 = Utils.getCert(PropertyUtils 
                                                .getProperty(Property.SIGN_ROOT_CERT0_PATH.value)); 
X509Certificate root1 = Utils.getCert(PropertyUtils 
                                                .getProperty(Property.SIGN_ROOT_CERT1_PATH.value)); 
X509Certificate[] chain =  {root1,root0};
```

i create pdfstamper , set values to PdfSignatureAppearance ( i create Cert. chain with issuer certificates ) and preclose PdfSignatureAppearance  to calculate hash of pdf.  and i send this hash to mobile signature service  they returns me certificate and signedvalue.  than i added this cert. to chain and continue signing process.

My problem is when i open the pdf file with adobe i only see one certificate ,  i can't see other two root certificate. i put link below it contains my code, a singe pdf  and the certificates i used.  can you help me ?

www dropbox.com/sh/g8yand5vlt5mxi8/I_mdANaJGC

Updated

at Image 1  i see only one cert. but i want to see like at Image 2. how can i put root cert. into pdf ?

Full Code

```
package com.dotto.mobilesign.sign;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertParser;
import org.etsi.uri.ts102204.v1_1.MSSSignatureRespType;

import com.dotto.mobilesign.types.Constant.FILE_TYPE;
import com.dotto.mobilesign.types.Constant.MESSAGE_TYPE;
import com.dotto.mobilesign.types.Constant.Property;
import com.dotto.mobilesign.types.dotto.AveaMobileSignResponse;
import com.dotto.mobilesign.util.ArchiveUtils;
import com.dotto.mobilesign.util.PropertyUtils;
import com.dotto.mobilesign.util.Utils;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.OcspClientBouncyCastle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfString;

public class PDFSignHelper {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PDFSignHelper.class.getName());
    private static String transId = "-1";
    private static byte[] pdfDataUnsigned;
    private static byte[] pdfDatasigned;

    public AveaMobileSignResponse signSync(String rawBase64File,
            String mobilePhone, String signText, FILE_TYPE fType,
            MESSAGE_TYPE mType) throws Exception {
        SignWSSyncHelper helper = new SignWSSyncHelper();
        AveaMobileSignResponse response = null;
        try {
            transId = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
            log.info("Trans Id : " + transId);
            pdfDataUnsigned = Utils.base64Decode(rawBase64File);
            log.info("PDF Data decoded");
            /*
             * Sign pdf
             */
            try {
                PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        pdfDataUnsigned));
                ByteArrayOutputStream signedPdf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                final PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(pdf,
                        signedPdf, '\0');
                log.info("PDF stamper created");
                PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
                X509Certificate root0 = Utils.getCert(PropertyUtils
                        .getProperty(Property.SIGN_ROOT_CERT0_PATH.value));
                X509Certificate root1 = Utils.getCert(PropertyUtils
                        .getProperty(Property.SIGN_ROOT_CERT1_PATH.value));

                X509Certificate[] chain =  {root1,root0};
                sap.setCrypto(null, chain, null,
                        PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);

                sap.setContact(PropertyUtils
                        .getProperty(Property.SIGN_CONTACT.value));
                sap.setReason(PropertyUtils
                        .getProperty(Property.SIGN_REASON.value));
                sap.setLocation(PropertyUtils
                        .getProperty(Property.SIGN_LOCATION.value));
                sap.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
                sap.setSignDate(cal);

                sap.setAcro6Layers(true);
                sap.setLayer2Text(signText);
                sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), 1,
                        "Signature");
                sap.setExternalDigest(new byte[128], new byte[20], "RSA");

                PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE,
                        new PdfName("adbe.pkcs7.detached"));
                dic.setReason(sap.getReason());
                dic.setLocation(sap.getLocation());
                dic.setContact(sap.getContact());
                dic.setDate(new PdfDate(sap.getSignDate()));
                sap.setCryptoDictionary(dic);
                log.info("PDF hash  creating");

                int contentEstimated = 35000;

                HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();
                exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, contentEstimated * 2 + 2);
                sap.preClose(exc);

                final MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest
                        .getInstance("SHA1");
                InputStream data = sap.getRangeStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                int n;
                while ((n = data.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                    messageDigest.update(buf, 0, n);
                }
                byte hash[] = messageDigest.digest();
                log.info("PDF hash  created");
                log.info("PDF hash  sended to sign for web service");
                MSSSignatureRespType signResponse = helper.signSyncron(transId,
                        Utils.base64Encode(hash), mobilePhone, signText);
                log.info("WS returns result");
                int statusCode = -1;
                String statusMessage = null;
                if (signResponse.getStatus() != null) {

                    if (signResponse.getStatus().getStatusCode() != null
                            && signResponse.getStatus().getStatusCode()
                                    .getValue() != null) {
                        statusCode = signResponse.getStatus().getStatusCode()
                                .getValue().intValue();
                    }
                    log.info("WS returns status code " + statusCode);

                    statusMessage = signResponse.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
                    log.info("WS returns status message " + statusMessage);

                    String errorText = "";
                    boolean error = true;
                    if (statusCode == 502) {
                        log.info(statusMessage);
                        error = false;
                        /*
                         * success
                         */
                    } else if (statusCode == -1) {
                        errorText = "Status Code : none Status Message : "
                                + statusMessage;
                    } else if (statusCode == 208) {
                        errorText = "Status Code : "
                                + statusCode
                                + " Status Message : "
                                + statusMessage
                                + ".  Message can't reach client Timeout. Response "
                                + helper.soapResponseText;
                    } else {
                        errorText = "Status Code : " + statusCode
                                + " Status Message : " + statusMessage
                                + ".  General Error . Response "
                                + helper.soapResponseText;
                    }
                    if (error) {
                        log.error(errorText);
                        throw new Exception(errorText);
                    }
                }

                /*
                 * Success
                 */
                response = new AveaMobileSignResponse();
                response.fileType = fType.getValue();
                response.messageType = mType.getValue();
                response.mobilePhone = mobilePhone;
                response.statusCode = statusCode;
                response.statusMessage = statusMessage;
                if (signResponse.getMSSSignature() == null) {
                    log.error("Signature Empty. " + helper.soapResponseText);
                    throw new Exception("Signature Empty. "
                            + helper.soapResponseText);
                }
                log.info("getting cert. and sign ");
                byte[] certificate = signResponse.getMSSSignature()
                        .getBase64Signature();
                X509CertParser certParser = new X509CertParser();
                certParser.engineInit(new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate));
                X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) certParser.engineRead();
                if (root0 != null) {
                    chain = new X509Certificate[3];
                    chain[0] = cer;
                    chain[1] = root1;
                    chain[2] = root0;
                } else {
                    chain = new X509Certificate[1];
                    chain[0] = cer;
                }

                PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, null, "SHA1", null,
                        true);
                byte[] signedHashValue = signResponse.getMSSSignature()
                        .getXMLSignature().getSignatureValue().getValue();

                String TSA_URL = PropertyUtils
                        .getProperty(Property.SIGN_TIMESTAMP_URL.value);
                String TSA_ACCNT = PropertyUtils
                        .getProperty(Property.SIGN_TIMESTAMP_ACC.value);
                String TSA_PASSW = PropertyUtils
                        .getProperty(Property.SIGN_TIMESTAMP_PSS.value);


                CustomTSAClient tsc=new CustomTSAClient(TSA_URL, Integer.parseInt(TSA_ACCNT), TSA_PASSW);

                //TSAClientBouncyCastle tsc=new TSAClientBouncyCastle("http://zd.e-guven.com/TSS/HttpTspServer");
                //TSAClient tsc = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(TSA_URL, TSA_ACCNT, TSA_PASSW);
                OcspClientBouncyCastle ocs = null;
                byte[] ocsp = null;
                if (chain.length >= 2) {
                    String url = PdfPKCS7.getOCSPURL(chain[0]);
                    if (url != null && url.length() > 0)
                        ocs = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
                    ocsp = ocs.getEncoded(chain[0], chain[1], url);
                }

                byte sh[] = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(signedHashValue,
                        cal, ocsp);
                sgn.update(sh, 0, sh.length);

                sgn.setExternalDigest(signedHashValue, hash, "RSA");

                byte[] paddedSig = new byte[contentEstimated];

                byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(null, cal, tsc, ocsp);
                System.arraycopy(encodedSig, 0, paddedSig, 0, encodedSig.length);
                if (contentEstimated + 2 < encodedSig.length)
                    throw new Exception("Not enough space for signature");

                PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
                dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS,
                        new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true));
                sap.close(dic2);
                log.info("inserting sign ");
                pdfDatasigned = signedPdf.toByteArray();
                response.signedRawBase64File = Utils
                        .base64Encode(pdfDatasigned);
                log.info("insertied sign ");
                ArchiveUtils.archive(transId, pdfDataUnsigned, pdfDatasigned,
                        fType, mType);
                return response;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error while signing. " + helper.soapResponseText, e);
                throw new Exception("Error while signing. "
                        + helper.soapResponseText, e);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Image 1 : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24426467/pdf-sign/img1.jpg
Image 2 : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24426467/pdf-sign/img2.jpg

Comment: Due to security concerns, I doubt many users will download your PDF.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have mixed up something. The following certificates are included in the CMS container in the PDF (non-ASCII characters might be somewhat mixed up):

1st:

> Subject: SERIALNUMBER=20000000002,C=TR,CN=GÃœNAY DEMÄ°R
>
> Issuer: CN=Avea Mobil Nitelikli Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet
>   Saglayicisi,O=Elektronik Bilgi Guvenligi A.S.,C=TR

2nd

> Subject: CN=e-Guven Nitelikli Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet
>   Saglayicisi,O=Elektronik Bilgi Guvenligi A.S.,C=TR
>
> Issuer: CN=e-Guven Kok Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet
>   Saglayicisi,O=Elektronik Bilgi Guvenligi A.S.,C=TR

3rd

> Subject: CN=Avea Mobil Nitelikli Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet
>   Saglayicisi,O=Elektronik Bilgi Guvenligi A.S.,C=TR
>
> Issuer: CN=e-Guven Kok Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet
>   Saglayicisi,O=Elektronik Bilgi Guvenligi A.S.,C=TR

1st is the signer certificate, 3rd is the intermediate CA certificate which is your "root 1.crt", but 2nd simply is yet another CA certificate based on the same root certificate.

The actual root certificate, "root.cer" in your drop box, is missing.

You might want to check the values of the properties referencing your root and CA certificates.

(And for clarity's sake, you should change the names of the variables and files to not call the intermediate CA certificate a root certificate.)